# Ansible: write whole facts to file

Tags: python, ansible

I collect some system specific data from my hosts (such as hostnam, os-release, disk usage ...) and save this information in a facts variable.

This works pretty well and the debug tasks returns all collected data.

Now I want to write this to a file:

```
---
- name: gather system information
  gather_facts: False
  hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - host_feature_config.yml

  vars:
    - tasks_out: []

  tasks:

    - name: get the remote-hostname
      shell: 'hostname'
      register: rhost

    - name: get the remote-features
      set_fact:
         host_features: "{{ (lookup('vars', rhost.stdout)) | join(' ') }}"

    - import_tasks: tasks_lib.yml

    - debug:
         msg: "{{ tasks_out }}"

    - local_action: 
         copy content="{{ tasks_out }}" dest=out/tasks_out.json
```

Unfortunately: the debug will display all values from all hosts correctly, but if you check the "tasks_out.json" only the data from the last scanned host is present.
It seems that the output (per host) gets overwritten instead of concaterneted.

How to save the whole text into tasks_out.json ?

**Update:**

So changing the code to:

```
    - copy: 
        content: "{% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}From host: {{ host }}\n{{ tasks_out }}\n{% endfor %}"
        dest: out/tasks_out.json
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

... will NOT change the issue. Still ansible will take only all the data from the first task and writes it to "out/tasks_out.json". But multiple times !

So when you have 5 hosts and you run your tasks on 'em. Ansible will take the output of the first host (all tasks) and writes it to your output file. But for the 2nd ... 5th it'll repeat the same output.

When you remove (or hash-out) the "run_once: true" you'll get the data from the last host (instead of the first)

All this is quite logical, but we still can say that Ansible overwrites the file any time a new host run its tasks.

How to concaternate the output instead of having Ansible to overwrite it ?

Comment: Well, unfortunately this is **not** a duplicate.

Following the linked answer will just save the content of the first file - and discards the rest. Instead of writing the infos from only the last host. So I still face the issue of concaternating all output (as produced my debug) into one file

Comment: You missed the fact that the duplicate answer tells you to use `hostvars[host].tasks_out` inside the loop, not just `tasks_out` as you do in your edit.